# Javascript global variable not working as expected

Tags: express, electron

I'm trying to use my "window" variable in express but i cant. Can anyone help

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron")
const expapp = require("express")()

this.window

app.on("ready", () => {
    this.window = new BrowserWindow({webPreferences:{ nodeIntegration: true }})

    this.window.loadURL("https://www.google.com.tr")
    expapp.get("/", (req,res) => {
        res.render("index.ejs")
    })
    /* Sayfayı geri al */
    expapp.get("/back", (req,res) => {
        this.window.selectPreviousTab()
        res.send("ok")
    })
})

expapp.listen(1661, () => { console.log("1661 portu üzerinden dinleniyor") })
```

when i go to this route in express "/back" i get this error

```
TypeError: this.window.selectPreviousTab is not a function
    at C:\Users\GreXLin85\Desktop\Projelerim\PC\xx\app.js:15:21
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\GreXLin85\Desktop\Projelerim\PC\xx\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\GreXLin85\Desktop\Projelerim\PC\xx\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\GreXLin85\Desktop\Projelerim\PC\xx\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\GreXLin85\Desktop\Projelerim\PC\xx\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\GreXLin85\Desktop\Projelerim\PC\xx\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\GreXLin85\Desktop\Projelerim\PC\xx\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\GreXLin85\Desktop\Projelerim\PC\xx\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (C:\Users\GreXLin85\Desktop\Projelerim\PC\xx\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\GreXLin85\Desktop\Projelerim\PC\xx\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read about `main` and `renderer` processes in electron:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-architecture#main-and-renderer-processes

In `main` process you don't have global `window` variable: `main` process is `node` process, not a browser one.

And `BrowserWindow` class has no `.selectPreviousTab()` method - it's not an `NSWindow` and you are not writing native code in `Swift`. You should use `electron`/`js` documentation not `native/Swift` documentation ofr developing `electron` apps.

`electron` is a **framework/platform** for writing desktop applications in `JS` using node and chromium, it is **not a native** framework.